# Qual a diferença de Owner para Parent?

Tags: delphi, terminologia

Quero saber qual a diferença **Owner** para **Parent** no Delphi?

Comment: Basicamente Owner é o PAI e Parent é o FILHO. alguns componentes precisão de um Owner para se hospedarem. Um exemplo disso é um TMemo, tecnicamente você não consegue utilizar ele visivelmente sem que ele tenha um Owner, no caso, ele nem apareceria na tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [Parent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Parent) de um TControl é o controle que o contém, por exemplo, se três radiobuttons estiverem dentro de um GroupBox então o GroupBox é o Parent deles.

Já o [Owner](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Owner) indica o componente responsável pela liberação daquele componente da memória

Digamos, por exemplo, que você cria um TEdit em RunTime, e passe o Form como Parent e Owner.

```
Edt := TEdit.Create(Form1);//Ao fazer isso você está dizendo que quando o Form1 for liberado da memória ele vai liberar o Edt também.
Edt.Parent := Form1;//Ao fazer isso você está dizendo que o Edt está dentro do Form1
```